# Spring boot rabbitmq message not getting requeued

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Hi I am trying to requeue certain messages if a specific exception is thrown, but for any validation failures I want them to go straight to the dead letter queue.  I have the the relevant queues and dead letter queues enabled.  I am finding hat my validation failures are got to the dlq, but the other failures are constantly in an unack state and getting constantly retried, beyond the max-attempts and multiplier I had set up, any ideas why this is?  code below  I am using Spring boot 2.0.4 release

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queuename}")
    public void consume(final @Valid @Payload MyRequest myRequest) {
        if (method.fail()) {
          throw new RuntimeException("");
        }
    }

 @Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory myHandlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2Converter());
    factory.setValidator(amqpValidator());
    return factory;
}

@Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myHandlerMethodFactory());
}

@Bean
public Validator amqpValidator() {
    return new OptionalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}


@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory =
            new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    listenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(
            new MyErrorPayload()));
    listenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return listenerContainerFactory;
}

 @Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitQueueHost);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitQueueUsername);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitQueuePassword);
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitQueueVirtualHost);
    return connectionFactory;
}



public class MyErrorPayload implements FatalExceptionStrategy {


@Override
public boolean isFatal(Throwable t) {
  if (t instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException &&
        (t.getCause() instanceof MessageConversionException ||
         t.getCause() instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException )
        ) {
      return true;
  }
    return false;
 }
}
```

**application.yml ( properties)**

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: uu
    password: pp
    virtual-host: /
    listener:
      simple:
        default-requeue-rejected: false
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 2000
          multiplier: 1.5
          max-interval: 10000
          max-attempts: 3
```

Comment: I think there are two different listener containers are being present. Did you debug to find which container has invoked isFatal ?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the retry activity. If you can't figure it out from that, post the logs someplace.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am able to reproduce the issue with this sample [global-handler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/spring-rabbit-global-errorhandler) by throwing RuntimeException in listener method and copied above application.yml. Could you please check ?

Comment: @Barath, thanks for pointing to that sample; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are not using Boot's auto configuration for the container factory. So the retry configuration is ignored.

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory =
            new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    listenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(
            new MyErrorPayload()));
    listenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return listenerContainerFactory;
}
```

The same was true for the sample that @Barath references in his comment.

Inject the configurer into your factory method and invoke it; for example, for that sample...

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    return factory;
}
```

If there is only one message converter Bean, the configurer will add that too.

I have updated the sample.

**EDIT**

Custom retry policy for selective exceptions; the following disables retry for `ValidationException` but retries all others. (Again, for the sample app)...

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, RabbitProperties properties) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    ListenerRetry retryConfig = properties.getListener().getSimple().getRetry();
    if (retryConfig.isEnabled()) {
        RetryInterceptorBuilder<?> builder = (retryConfig.isStateless()
                ? RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                : RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful());
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions = Collections
                .singletonMap(ValidationException.class, false);
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(retryConfig.getMaxAttempts(),
                retryableExceptions, true, true); // retry all exceptions except Validation
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(retryConfig.getInitialInterval().toMillis());
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(retryConfig.getMaxInterval().toMillis());
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(retryConfig.getMultiplier());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        builder.retryOperations(retryTemplate);
        builder.recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer());
        factory.setAdviceChain(builder.build());
    }
    return factory;
}
```

No messages are ever requeued since you have `default-requeue-rejected: false`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this I have included this and yes the retries are now working, however my custom error handler doesn't seem to be getting invoked now, so everything is getting retried three times including the validation failures, any ideas?

Comment: Also I have an integration test to test when the message the is put back on the queue for retry, by doing a queue count, I would expect it to show as there being 1 message still on queue, but it shows as zero, is this because the message is in the unack state?

 Integer failedMsgcountBefore = (Integer) this.amqpAdmin.getQueueProperties(queue)
                .get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT");

Comment: That is normal. You need a custom retry policy for selective exception retries. I can help later if you need help with that. You are using stateless retry so it's retried in memory not put back on the queue. But in any case it will redelivered immediately  even with stateful recovery, if there is only 1 message or prefetch is 1.

Comment: I think I will need that help, got myself confused. Is my custom error handler now redundant if I need a custom retry policy? Also would having stateful recovery mean I would get a queue count, when I ask for it? In stateless mode if the queues went down, would that not mean the message would be lost; so statefull would be better? Appreciate the help given so far thanks a lot

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with your custom error handler; I would have expected to see some logic around `ValidationException` but, since you have `default-requeue-rejected=false`, you really don't need a custom error handler - that's only needed if you want to control which exceptions are requeued and which are not. No, stateless retry won't cause message loss. No, you won't get a queue count, because, as I said, the message will be immediately redelivered (and the retry policy will sleep the thread. I will edit my answer with a custom retry policy.

Comment: Thanks Gary so much seems to be working now.  When a validation error occurs, it throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException, which my custom error handler was trying to manage, the intention of it was to control the exceptions I wanted to dead letter and those I didn't.  The solution was based off this blog here

https://blog.trifork.com/2016/02/29/spring-amqp-payload-validation/

Comment: If I had say 30k non fatal failures, if the messages don't go back onto the queue, how many threads would actually be active and sleeping here?  Sorry if that sounds like a dumb question

Comment: Sorry; yes, I forgot that validation failures are thrown as `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, not `ValidationException`. The number of threads depends on the concurrency of the container (default 1). The retry interceptor suspends the listener container thread during backOff, regardless of stateful/stateless retry.